# how to change colour of loading icon

Tags: ios, xcode, refresh

I want to change the colour of the loading icon that comes up after pulling to refresh this is my code for the indicatorviewstyle i think this is related to doing what i want but i didnt write the code, its from: https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl

```
-(void)setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:  (UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle)activityIndicatorViewStyle
{
if ([_activity isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]]) {
    [(UIActivityIndicatorView *)_activity setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:activityIndicatorViewStyle];
}
}

- (UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle)activityIndicatorViewStyle
{
if ([_activity isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]]) {
    return [(UIActivityIndicatorView *)_activity activityIndicatorViewStyle];
}
return 0;
}

- (void)setActivityIndicatorViewColor:(UIColor *)activityIndicatorViewColor
{
if ([_activity isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]] && [_activity respondsToSelector:@selector(setColor:)]) {
    [(UIActivityIndicatorView *)_activity setColor:activityIndicatorViewColor];
}
}


- (UIColor *)activityIndicatorViewColor
{
if ([_activity isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]] && [_activity respondsToSelector:@selector(color)]) {
    return [(UIActivityIndicatorView *)_activity color];
}
return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file ODRefreshControl.m , change the following line in

```
- (id)initInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView activityIndicatorView:(UIView *)activity
```

from

```
_activity = activity ? activity : [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

to

```
_activity = activity ? activity : [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
```

Comment: thanks, its working now! you have been really helpful today :)